# How do I stop my list getting reset when I run my game?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine

I have a class with a list of game objects in it set up like this:

```
public class ObjectList : MonoBehaviour {

public List<GameObject> listOfObjects;
```

I have another class creates objects and then adds them to the listOfObjects like this (this is a cut down version of the function):

```
public void InsertToList(Vector3Int myPosition)
    {
        GameObject g = GameObject.Find("Grid");
        ObjectList listScript = g.GetComponent<ObjectList>();
        GameObject tileObject = new GameObject("test");
        listScript.listOfObjects.Add(tileObject);
    }
```

I fill my listOfObjects in the editor but when I run the game it seems to wipe it and I'm not sure why. [Heres a gif of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR2jy.gif)

I tried adding [SerializeField] above the listOfObjects but that didnt seem to solve it. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: share some more code i think that you are resting listOfObjects in any script.

Comment: Not an answer, more like an advice: I can suggest using `ScriptableObject` to keep your data and reference it from other `MonoBehaviours`. In that case things that are kept in a scriptable object sould survive switch to playmode.